# Using Java Streams to filter list based on grandchildren attributes

Tags: java, java-stream

## Problem

I am wanting to use streams to filter a list based on whether or not a instance exists in the bottom level of a hierarchy.
So I have `List<Summary>` -> `Group` -> `Summary` -> `Person` and I want to be able to filter this down to include entries where at least one of the subgroups does not contain any people under the age of 30.   If this criteria is met I want to keep that `Summary`.

I ideally want to use plain Java and I am stuck on JDK-8 due to the application this is hosted on.  I cannot seem to figure out the right way to nest the streams to achieve this.

I have got this far but it misses cases where there isn't a subgroup or where there are no people in the subgroup and I am not entirely convinced this is the correct logic

```
summaries.stream()
  .filter (s -> s.getGreoup().getSubGroups.stream()
    .anyMatch(sg -> sg.getPeople.stream()
      .noneMatch(p -> p.getAge() < 30)))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

## Classes

I have `List<Summary>` which I want to filter and this breaks down as

```
public class Summary {
  Group aGroup;
  Long numPeople;
  String manager;
}
```

of which there are multiple instances in a `List`.
I then have

```
public Class Group {
  List<SubGroup> subGroups;
  //...
}
```

```
public Class SubGroup {
  List<Person> people;
  //...
}
```

```
public class Person  {
  String name;
  int age;
  //...
}
```

Comment: But if there are no people in the subgroup, it doesn't contain any people under 30.
I'd advise you to break down each of the requirements and check them separately rather than inlining them all into a stream in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Predicate<SubGroup> isU30OnlySubGroup = subGroup ->
 subGroup.getPeople().stream().allMatch(person -> person.getAge() >= 30);

Predicate<Summary> hasU30OnlySubGroup = summary -> 
 summary.getGroup().getSubGroups().stream().anyMatch(isU30OnlySubGroup);

List<Summary> filteredSummaries = 
 summaries.stream().filter(hasU30OnlySubGroup).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Needed an additional predicate and an or to cater for groups with no subgroups but that helped a lot.   Thanks